# Excel Data Validation List not visible

Tags: microsoft-excel, data-validation, office-for-mac

I am trying to make a dynamic calendar in Excel 2018 for myself through watching YouTube video tutorial. But I am constantly having a problem with "Data Validation" not displaying the list. Just a few moments ago, it was working fine then it's not now. I haven't touched any settings but it keeps going on and off for some reason...

So I've selected the 'list' in data validation pop up. The downward arrow is always displayed but whenever I click on it, the list I've included doesn't unfold/show. In other words, the arrow is doing nothing.

I've tried some instructions by others such as:
(1) Don't leave any blank cells
(2) Select 'Ignore blank', and 'In-cell dropdown' in Data Validation pop up
(3) Select and name the desired range

But they weren't so helpful...

If you could help me how to fix this problem it would be really helpful! I don't know whether it is helpful to fix this or not but I use Mac!

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the Data Validation definition dialogue box, showing how the list is set up / the source for it?

Answer (score 0):

the screenshots come from my mac. Perhaps a comparison will let you figure out your issue.

[image: data validation definition dialog box]

[image: excel result]